# How can I perform an NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate where the predicate is a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, predicate

How can I perform an NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate where the predicate is a method?  That is what would a simple code example look like here?

I've been trying to go through the predicate doco and getting a little confused.  I can see how it works for simple checks, but if I have a check which requires a few lines of objective-c code to implement what would the code look like to effectively:

- filter an NSArray using filteredArrayUsingPredicate
- predicate would be a method which somehow takes an input variable(s), performs whatever checks and balances and then gives a TRUE/FALSE back as a return value re whether the item should be filtered or not

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're going with iOS 4.0 and above you'll be glad to know this is really straightforward (the following isn't available on 3.x).

You can use the `predicateWithBlock` method to create a NSPredicate that takes a block that returns YES or NO as its argument. So pretty much exactly what you want (if you're not familiar with blocks they're basically a way to encapsulate a method. See here: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1)

`+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block`

Comment: great - I've done some Ruby so it's good to hear objective-c can support this

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `predicateWithBlock:` approach that @lxt suggested, or you can use the `FUNCTION` approach.  This would have you build a predicate that looks like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION(SELF, 'mySuperMethod:', %@)", aParameter];
```

If you use that predicate to filter an array, then:

- `SELF` will iteratively be each item in the array
- each item in the array will have its `-mySuperMethod:` method invoked
- `-mySuperMethod:` will receive `aParameter` as the parameter to the method
- `-mySuperMethod:` will return a `BOOL` *that has been boxed in an `NSNumber`* << this is very important
- all of the objects that return `YES` from `-mySuperMethod:` will be included in the filtered array.

For more information on this syntax, check out [this blog post](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression).

So why might you want to use this approach over the block approach?  I can think of two reasons:

- Backwards Compatibility

  - If you need this to work on Leopard (blocks on the Mac were introduced in Snow Leopard).
  - If you need this to work on iOS pre-4.0 (blocks on iOS were introduced in iOS 4.0).
- You want to serialize the predicate for archival and later retrieval.  This is fine as long as `aParameter` conforms to the `<NSCoding>` protocol.  Blocks cannot be serialized.

However, if neither of those are requirements, then the block approach will probably be better in the long run, since it's more obvious and readable.  :)

Comment: thats for pointing this out - wasn't sure which to mark as correct answer noting both were good - went with the first answer in the end noting your last sentence